# Как отложить синтаксический анализ JavaScript

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как отложить синтаксический анализ JavaScript
Для 2х скриптов на странице, первым загружается Jquery а вторым его плагин.
Пробовал сделать так

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.defer= true;
    ga.src = "http://site.ru/js/plagin.js"
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);

  })();
</script>
```

но в консоли ошибка Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined  -- plagin.js

Comment: что вы хотите  ?   :) поменьше умных слов :) см ответ:

Comment: @eicto: ответ отвалился по дороге? :)

Comment: @Vlad кнопки долго нажимал :) на месте ответ

Comment: @eicto: тогда +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

просто выполняйте загрузку второго скрипта после первого (`onload`);

```
var ga = document.createElement('script');
ga.type = 'text/javascript';
ga.async = true;
ga.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js";
document.head.appendChild(ga);
ga.onload = function () {
    var ga = document.createElement('script');
    ga.type = 'text/javascript';
    ga.defer = true;
    ga.src = "http://site.ru/js/plagin.js";
    ga.onload = all_other;
    document.head.appendChild(ga);
};
document.head.appendChild(ga);

function all_other() {
    $(function () {
        console.log('Hello jquery and plugin loaded, document ready!');
    });
}
```